# Prediction of n class variables

Tags: r, regression, classification, prediction, weka

I have a historical data that has discrete variables.
 Let say I have data points with class labels

```
1, 2, 3, 4, and 5
```

For a given classification problem, I can use the training data and then get the trained model. Using the trained model, I can classify the labels. However, I am also interested in prediction of class labels.

My requirement is that for a given $N$ points, lets say 5 data points, I want to know what is the probability that class label 5 more likely or less likely occurs from 0 to 1. Can anyone give me any ideas on this? For example my output will be a prediction probability for 5 instances, being:

0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5.

This means that the first data point has zero probability for class label 5 to occur. The 5th data point has the highest probability to occur around 50%. Can anyone give me idea on how to go about this problem?

Comment: It seems to me that the prediction value will come from the mechanism that you use to build your model. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Use softmax with 5 class outputs. It outputs class probabilities whose sum is 1. You may stack it to Neural network to construct more complex model.

Comment: I want predicted probabilites rather than classification. If I have 3 class labels, I want to know which has more probability to occur from 0 to 1. Let's say we have class labels that robot can function or not, probability 0 means robot cannot function and probability 1 means robot can function. Anything in between 0 and 1 is the state of robot initializing its CPU.

Answer (score 1):

First let me rephrase the problem to make sure I understand it: you have 5 points, but you don't want to classify the points, you want classification *probabilities*.

If that's the case, that's what [multinomial regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) (Wikipedia) is designed to do. It's covered in several textbooks; I learned out of [Categorical Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470463635) (Amazon link to 3e)  by Agresti but it might not be the best book for self-study.

You can also use a [neural network](http://briandolhansky.com/blog/2013/9/23/artificial-neural-nets-linear-multiclass-part-3) (blog post by Brian Dolhansky) that outputs class membership probabilities. Interesting coverage of the subject [here](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yi_Murphey/publication/222409958_Multi-class_pattern_classification_using_neural_networks/links/0c96051c9959d57e2d000000.pdf) (Ou and Murphey, 2007, Multi-class pattern classification using neural networks. *Pattern Recognition* 40, 4-18).

Comment: You're correct. I want predicted probabilites rather than classification. If I have 3 class labels, I want to know which has more probability to occur from 0 to 1. Let's say we have class labels that robot can function or not, probability 0 means robot cannot function and probability 1 means robot can function. Anything in between 0 and 1 is the state of robot initializing its CPU. I am trying to figure out which model can fit this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand what you are asking... You can determine the probability of getting class label 5 btwn 0 and 1 by simply adding the probability of getting 5 @ 0 & prob of getting 5 @ 1 (p(0) + p(1) = 0 + .1 = .1)

Solution: Since Prob of getting class 5 btwn 2 & 4 would be--> p(2) + p(3) + p(4) = .2 + .3 + .5 = .9 & prob of 5 btwn 0 & 1 = p(0) + p(1) = 0 + .1 = .1

.9 > .1 Thus Class label 5 is less likely to be btwn 0 & 1.